# How to be compatible with like syntax after upgrading Hibernate Search 6.x version

Tags: sql, elasticsearch, hibernate-search, hibernate-search-6

I recently upgraded hibernate search from version 5.x to version 6.x, and encountered some problems. Most grammars can be processed by referring to the document, but there is a like grammar that cannot be processed directly. The official document also gives a description, However, the content of the document is not detailed enough and cannot be completed.
This is my syntax for 5.x version `queryBuilder.moreLikeThis().comparingFields("name").toEntity(product).createQuery()`
But I want to use the 6.x version and I don't know how to transform it for the time being

Hope someone who knows can answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the migration guide, the `moreLikeThis` predicate doesn't exist anymore in Hibernate Search 6.

But if it's just about a single field, you didn't really need the `moreLikeThis` predicate to begin with.

This should return the same results as your current code:

```java
SearchSession session = Search.session(entityManager);
List<Product> hits = session.search(Product.class)
        .where(f -> f.match().field("name").matching(product.getName()))
        .fetchHits(20);
```

Comment: I have tried to write your method, but the search results are still a little different. I probably understand what you mean, but my actual code is like multiple attributes. In fact, I want to use the elasticsearch syntax to deal with it. Is there a more complete example for reference?

Comment: If you want to use the Elasticsearch more-like-this, you'll have to build the JSON document manually. But feel free; [here's](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-dsl-predicate-extensions-elasticsearch-from-json) how to define a predicate from JSON using `ElasticsearchExtension` and `f.fromJson`.